# replace all rare words from the text (substitute very large number of strings in a large text)

Tags: r

I have a large text and wanted to replace all the words that have low frequency, with some marker, example "^rare^".  My document is 1.7 million lines and after cleaning it up it has 482,932 unique words, out of which more than 400 thousand occur less than 6 these are the ones that I want to replace.

Couple ways that I know how take longer than is practical.  For instance I just tried `mgsub` from `qdap` package.

```
test <- mgsub(rare, "<UNK>", smtxt$text)
```

Where `rare` is a vector of all the rare words and `smtxt$text` is the vector that holds all the text, one sentence per row.

R is still processing it.

I think, since each word is begin checked against each sentence this is expected.  For now I am resigned to forget about doing something like this.  I would like to hear for others if there is another way. Since I still have not looked into many option besides what I know: `gsub`, and `mgsub` and also tried turning the text into corpus to see if it will process faster.

Thanks

Comment: check out gsub with perl=TRUE

Comment: I have used regular expressions and gsub before and that is what I know so far know about `perl = T` argument but is there a way to match thousands of words some of which I don't even know the structure of with this perl=TRUE, thanks.

Comment: is it possible to use something like `pattern = \b("word1|word2|word3")\b`.

Comment: @Bhail yes, I think that would be a good optimisation to try. Maybe sort the vector of rare words before combining into a single pattern as well.

Comment: @Marius, thanks I am testing it out.